# Visual studio shows no vertical scroll bar

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I'm using VS2022 and I'm trying to get rid of these sign:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I don't know what I did to make it appear, but it essentially goes down a line when the text reaches the end of the editor, instead of showing the scroll bar.

Any idea how to get back my vertical scroll bar?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOkuP.png

Comment: [word wrap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/how-to-manage-word-wrap-in-the-editor?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Hmm, it would be the *horizontal* scrollbar that is missing.  Use Edit > Advanced > Word Wrap to correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this problem affects multiple files, turn off word wrap from `Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > General`.

If it affects a single file, then turn off word wrap from `Edit > Advanced > Word Wrap` with the file open.

If that doesn't help, go to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Scroll Bars` and make sure both of these boxes are checked:

1. Show horizontal scroll bar
2. Show vertical scroll bar

[image]